# Building chains from nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list

I have a nested list:

```
[['мама', 'мыть', '10', 'рама'],
 ['мыть', 'рама', '5', 'долго'],
 ['мама', 'мыть', '10', 'рама'],
 ['мыть', 'рама', '3', 'вчера'],
 ['мыть', 'рама', '10', 'вчера'],
 ['рама', 'вчера', '1', 'поздно']]
```

What I need is to build chains where last two non-digital string elements  of one list are equal to first two non-digital string elements of another list, for example in:

```
['Мама', 'мыть', '10', 'рама']
```

and

```
['мыть', 'рама', '5', 'долго']
```

`'мыть', 'рама'` are a match, so the final output should be:

```
[['мама', 'мыть', '10', 'рама', '5', 'долго'],
 ['мама', 'мыть', '10', 'рама', '3', 'вчера'],
 ['мама', 'мыть'  '10', 'рама', '3', 'вчера', '1', 'поздно']]
```

Digits are kind of probability and should be left as is. I think there should be some kind of iterative search, but I am not sure.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `'мыть', 'рама'` are not the last two element of first list.

Comment: Maybe he meant non-digit strings only?

Comment: @AliYılmaz Thanks for your reply. I meant any string elements.

Comment: They're all strings though. And some of the strings contain numbers.

Comment: @gilch Edited my question, now should be more clear. Thanks!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Thanks for your reply. Edited the question, I meant  non-digital string elements only.

Comment: Looks like an [itinerary reconstruction](https://leetcode.com/problems/reconstruct-itinerary/description/) problem.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Create a dictionary from your list, with the key being the first two words, combined. Something like:

```
key: 'Мама_мыть' value: ['Мама', 'мыть', '10', 'рама'],
key: 'мыть_рама' value: ['мыть', 'рама', '5', 'долго'],
   ... etc ...
```

2 - Iterate over your list, creating a key from the last two non-numeric values in each entry. And look that value up in the dictionary.

3 - When you find a match, create the output.

Comment: I'd suggest using a tuple pair instead of string concatenation. Tuples are also sortable and hashable in Python.

Comment: @glich That'd work. I'm not much of a Python programmer, so I suggested the string. Feel free to edit my answer or supply your own more Python-like.

Comment: @JimMischel First of all, thanks for for your answer! I tried it, but this is not an option since we will have duplicate keys: ['мыть', 'рама', '5', 'долго'], ['мыть', 'рама', '10', 'вчера'].

Comment: @AlexNikitin You could modify the dictionary so that the value is a list of lists, rather than a single list.